# Android game using HTML5 and Javascript - Adapting images to different screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, android, html, screen, resolution

I am developing a simple game for android phones using HTML5, javascript and wrapping it up using cordova. In my game I plan to use an image as a background and pan it to produce a moving background effect. My major concern is the resolution of the background image and how to adapt it to different screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an image file that's as large as your largest possible resolution.
Then use to code to scale it for smaller images.